# How do I customise my Plymouth theme?

Tags: plymouth

I want to update my splash screen (when I boot or logoff), logo etc... to use the solar theme.

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-solar
```

then I went to the themes folder to customize it:

```
/lib/plymouth/themes/
```

and I updated logos and other images:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

I think this command is the right one to run but when I run it, nothing is updated

What am I missing?

Comment: `whereis plymouth`. plymouth: /bin/plymouth /lib/plymouth, `ls /lib/plymouth`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do the trick:

> sudo apt-get install galternatives
>
> sudo galternatives

Then select your theme from key `default-plymouth` and do the `update-initramfs -u` again.

Comment: (Ubuntu 12.10) Tried this and it didn't work :(. I first downloaded plymouth-manager, installed the stargate theme, and then I applied the installed theme. On a computer restart, it didn't show up. I then issued "update-initramfs -u", did another restart and it still didn't work. Anyone know how to fix this? EDIT: Also, installed and tried galternatives

Comment: In my case (Lubuntu 14.04) I was unable to select the me from list - instantly after either switching manual/auto mode in Status dropdown or selecting one of positions in list by using selection box in Choice column my selection flickered briefly and was undone to the previous state. Solution in the https://askubuntu.com/questions/228041/how-to-change-the-splash-screen at least claims to changed something.

Comment: After rebooting - yes, https://askubuntu.com/questions/228041/how-to-change-the-splash-screen works.