# What alternatives are available to replace the purple boot splash screen?

Tags: plymouth

I would love an animated splash screen, just for a bit of eye candy to replace the purple splash (with 4 dots) during the boot sequence. I know it will slow down boot time but I don't care I just want it to look good. When I show my friends how much better looking Ubuntu is than windows the splash really lets it down.

Any one know a good alternative to the existing Plymouth boot?

I could not get mine to change the splash screen (with terminal or gui apps), and it is now broken, it just shows a load of error messages at boot but still starts Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82434/how-do-i-customise-my-plymouth-theme

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82434/how-do-i-customise-my-plymouth-theme). That question is about how to fix a problem installing a particular theme, and it (potentially) generalizes to the question of how to install any Plymouth theme. In contrast, this question is about *what* Plymouth themes are available (and should perhaps be made community wiki).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I customize the Ubuntu boot up logo?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Ubuntu Sunrise (plymouth)

I use an old favorite **"Ubuntu Sunrise"** in 12.04 (In fact I have been using it since 10.04 LTS). It's easy to install (instructions below) and it has never caused me any issues. However you should note that changing your Plymouth may cause resolution issues depending on your own resolution.

[image: Ubuntu Sunrise]

**INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS**

**Step 1:**

Download the Plymouth Sunrise deb file [from here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ubuntu+sunrise+plymouth?content=129696).

**Step 2:**

Open the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and type

```
gksudo nautilus
```

**Step 3**

- Copy `ubuntu-sunrise` folder to `/lib/plymouth/themes`
- Copy the file splash into `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d` (Optional, for better buffer)

**Step 4:**

Type in the terminal

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-sunrise/ubuntu-sunrise.plymouth 200
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

**Step 5:**

Choose the number associated with `ubuntu-sunrise` in the options that pop up.

**Step 6**

Type in the terminal

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

**Then**

```
sudo reboot
```

**That's it.**

**Note:** Some people have issues installing other Plymouth themes (I've never had any) and I would strongly advise you to take a look at [these issues here at Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=plymouth%20resolution) to familiarise yourself.

Comment: Thanks man will look into this this afternoon and get back to you.

Comment: I ran into problems with the code in step 4 but one of the files contains a shell script (.sh) for it so I got it going but it shows up at shutdown and not start up any idea why?

Comment: @markkirby: Apologies I edited step 4.

Comment: Wish Canonical would make things like this default.

Comment: @heisenberg I've tweaked plymouth themes in the past (currently using [console/text - boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode)) but never did a - _initramfs-update_.. was that the reason which made the bootup slow after making the edits?

Answer (score 7):

### Changing the boot-splash colour from Purple to Black (but maintain the Ubuntu logo)

If you don't like the purple screen when you first turn on the computer and want to change it to black.

**Here are the instructions to accomplish this.**

1. Open the file `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script`
   with a text editor
2. Find the two lines quoted below in the script
3. Change all the values in the brackets to “0” then save the file

   ```
   Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0); # Nice colour on top of the screen fading to 
   Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0); # an equally nice colour on the bottom
   ```
4. Run the following command in the terminal

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

The colour of the boot splash background will now be black instead of purple when you reboot.

Answer (score 5):

### Up-Ubuntu Theme (Plymouth)

Up Ubuntu is another alternative to replace the default Purple boot splash screen

It can been downloaded from devianART (Instructions below)

[image]

---

**Installation Instructions**

**Step 1**

Download the Up-Ubuntu Plymouth theme from DevianArt by clicking **[here](http://pegel.deviantart.com/gallery/#/d45zil3)** 
(These instructions assume you use you default Download folder in ~/Home)

**Note:** Make sure the tar.gz file is extracted from the Zip file in downloads

**Step 2**

Open your terminal ((<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>)) and navigate to the Plymouth Theme folder using the following code

```
cd /lib/plymouth/themes/
```

**Step 3**

Copy the file to the plymouth theme folder using the following command

```
sudo cp -r /home/***/Downloads/U-p/ ./
```

(note : *** = is a your user directory, so change it as your name)

**Step 4**

Type in the following code

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/U-p/U-p.plymouth 100
```

Then

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

**Step 5**

Chose **U-p** or the corresponding number from the list presented

**Step 6**

To complete the installation type

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot your PC `sudo reboot` and your done

Answer (score 3):

### Use your favourite Wallpaper to replace the Purple boot splash

These instructions will show you how to replace the Purple Boot Splash with a desktop wallpaper of your choice.

**2 things to keep in mind**

1. Ensure the desktop wallpaper is the correct resolution for you your
   monitor
2. Unlike the other answers here there is no animation

---

**Instructions**

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/plymouth/themes/simple
```

This will create a folder called "simple"

Next: **Find a wallpaper that you wan't to use.**

Make sure that wallpaper is and rename the wallpaper as **wallpaper.png**

You now need  paste **wallpaper.png** into the **"simple"** folder

Open Nautilus as root by typing `gksu nautilus` in the terminal

Copy wallpaper to: `/lib/plymouth/themes/simple/` then close nautilus

---

**Return to the terminal  and type:**

```
sudo gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/simple/simple.plymouth
```

In gedit paste:

> [Plymouth Theme]
>
> Name=Simple
>
> Description=Wallpaper only
>
> ModuleName=script
>
> [script]
>
> ImageDir=/lib/plymouth/themes/simple
>
> ScriptFile=/lib/plymouth/themes/simple/simple.script

Save it and close.

---

Type the following into the terminal

```
sudo gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/simple/simple.script
```

**In gedit paste:**

> wallpaper_image = Image(“wallpaper.png”);
>
> screen_width = Window.GetWidth();
>
> screen_height = Window.GetHeight();
>
> resized_wallpaper_image =
>   wallpaper_image.Scale(screen_width,screen_height);
>
> wallpaper_sprite = Sprite(resized_wallpaper_image);
>
> wallpaper_sprite.SetZ(-100);

**Save it and close.**

---

**Now run:**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/simple/simple.plymouth 100
```

**then:**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

and select **simple** from list.

**To complete the installation type:**

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Thats it! When you `sudo reboot` you will see your wallpaper instead of the purple boot splash.