# How to Roll Back to Original Plymouth Splash

Tags: plymouth

The title says it all.  It's a bit of an eyesore with propriety NVIDIA drivers, so I tried [here](http://idyllictux.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/lucidubuntu-10-04-high-resolution-plymouth-virtual-terminal-for-atinvidia-cards-with-proprietaryrestricted-driver/). I'm pretty sure I reversed all settings, when it did not work for me. But now:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Returns error:

```
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I just wanna revert back to the vanilla 12.04 LTS Plymouth splash. Thanks. Also:

```
sudo gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth
```

Returns:

"The number of followed links is limited and the actual file could not be found within this limit."

EDIT: Should I restore from image backup (I see this filed as bug on Launchpad.)  Or is there a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your default.plymouth alternatives links are broken.

```
cd /lib/plymouth/themes
ls -l default.plymouth
```

Should give you

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Oct 25  2011 default.plymouth -> /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth
```

And

```
cd /etc/alternatives
ls -l default.plymouth
```

Should give you a link pointing to a .plymouth file in the /lib/plymouth/themes directory. E.g. For the default splash this should be pointing at:
    /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth

If not fix the links. You should then be able to configure plymouth in the normal way.

Comment: I restored from image backup in the end, so cannot verify this method, anyone else verify & I will accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps:**

**Step 1:**

Type into the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T)

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

**Step 2:**

Choose the number associated with `the default plymouth` in the options that pop up.

**Step 3**

Type in the terminal

```
sudo update-initramfs –u
```

**Then**

```
sudo reboot
```

Also have a [look at this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173329/what-alternatives-are-available-to-replace-the-purple-boot-splash-screen/173340#173340) if you want an alternative Plymouth that works

Comment: You probably read the title but not the body of question.