# How to change boot logo on a Live USB stick?

Tags: boot, plymouth

I'm making a little Live USB with my own distro, nicknamed "Hackbuntu" - it is basically a little bootable USB drive that you plug into a computer, boot it up, and then feel like a ninja when you're off visiting Onionland and decrypting Truecrypt volumes.

I can pretty much hanlde setting it up the way I like, but I want to change the default boot logo, the white "ubuntu" on a purple background, to a light green "hackbuntu" on a dark, dark green background. (The way that Lubuntu displays "lubuntu" on a sky blue background during boot-up.)

I can't figure out how to do this, however. I've found a few goodies in `/syslinux`, but I can't manage to get it customized all the way. I need someone to explain all that I need to do, because it appears that quite a bit of the "image" is actually rendered from info provided in configuration files. (e.g., `/syslinux/bootlogo` is making me NUTS trying to figure out what to do with it... It's a CPIO archive with some sort of binary file called `init` inside of it...)

- I've read [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth), but it doesn't give much info on how to customize live media... My USB drive is only 4 Gig, so installing a normal install on the USB stick is out of the picture...
- I've already seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/173329/95681), which does not explain how to customize live media. (Live Media, such as a Live USB drive, lacks the  `/lib/plymouth` directory entirely, making all answers from the aforementioned question invalid.)

Comment: `/usr/share/plymouth`