# Purple color of Boot splash screen not changing

Tags: boot, plymouth

I am trying to change the Boot purple screen to black so I searched to find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173329/what-alternatives-are-available-to-replace-the-purple-boot-splash-screen).
I followed the [last answer (by heisenberg)](https://askubuntu.com/a/258664/176889) saying:

> If you don't like the purple screen when you first turn on the
>   computer and want to change it to black.
>
> **Here are the instructions to accomplish this.**
>
> 1. Open the file `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script`
>      with a text editor
> 2. Find the two lines quoted below in the script
> 3. Change all the values in the brackets to “0” then save the file
>
>    ```
>    Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0); # Nice colour on top of the screen fading to 
>    Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0); # an equally nice colour on the bottom
>    ```
> 4. Run the following command in the terminal
>
>    ```
>    sudo update-initramfs -u
>    ```
>
> The colour of the boot splash background will now be black instead of
>   purple when you reboot.

I've opened the `ubuntu-logo.script` file with gedit but am unable to save it. Where am i wrong?

Comment: consider that you can also make an image as a splash screen instead of using nice colours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to open the file with root previlege

```
gksu gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script
```

and then change the values and you can save it.

Comment: what is the color format used there. what is meant by (0.0, 0.00, 0.0). I don't think it is normal RGB values. Because as I know, they cannot be decimal numbers in RGB values?

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga The color format is in percentage RGB. http://www.colorhexa.com/4dbcff was helpful for me to find the colour I wanted. Example: rgb(0, 159, 255), in percentage rgb(0%,62.4%,100%) means 0.0, 0.62, 1.0 for the ubuntu-logo.script.