# How to install "plymouth-greeter"?

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.10, plymouth

I'm bored my plymouth, and i would like to change this.
I found on the internet nice script.
https://launchpad.net/plymouth-greeter
When I try install this i can't but it is rly old. I use Ubuntu 14.10. Plymouth-greeter was written for Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10.
I try add this repository manualy using Synaptic.
It doesn't work... Repository is not exist at this moment.
How can I install it?
ppa:shnatsel/plymouth - repository added by me.

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/shnatsel/plymouth/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
http://ppa.launchpad.net/shnatsel/plymouth/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download packages from here:

https://launchpad.net/~shnatsel/+archive/ubuntu/plymouth/+packages

You should be able to install .deb package automatically. .tar.gz contains the files thrown in an archive. I am not familiar with .dsc

Comment: I installed it from **~.deb** package. That Doesn't work... I am a novice in these matters.

Comment: After second instalation works, but doesn't look good. http://i.imgur.com/kWf3Qf0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is an abandoned proof-of-concept PPA that should have been deleted a long time ago.  The screens you saw are mock-ups, so *please* don't install this PPA and if you did, reverse the installation of any software from it and then delete the PPA.

For more background information, [have a look here](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926).

Comment: OK I uninstalled it, but I still have the same problem and it was already as I turned on the loading screen. http://i.imgur.com/HEGSGwy.jpg Previously, I had the word "Ubuntu 14.10" and the inscription dots ... I did not like it, and I started to change it, at the very beginning I changed the boot screen resolution

Comment: That's a new question, which already has an answer here: [Alternative splash screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/173329/what-alternatives-are-available-to-replace-the-purple-boot-splash-screen).  As you're a reputation 1 user: My answer answered your original question so don't forget to click the grey **☑** under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)