# How to Change the Splash Screen

Tags: 12.04, plymouth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I customise my Plymouth theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82434/how-do-i-customise-my-plymouth-theme)

I have used a lot of tools to change the Ubuntu splash screen during boot, but the splash screen doesn't change. Please tell me what I should do to change the splash screen in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Thank You.

Comment: Note that this question has answer that unlike (outdated? failing in Lubuntu?) answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/82434/how-do-i-customise-my-plymouth-theme work also in Lubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 5):

To change the splash screen you can run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Select the alternative splash that you want. Then run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: This worked great on Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop as well.