# Installing desktop environment changed BG in GRUB2

Tags: 12.04, grub2, desktop-environments

As a Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 32-bit user I have installed various desktop environments and discovered that somehow the loading screen and the background of GRUB2 changed from pink to grey together with a change in the icon displaying during the initial loading before user login. To revert the change I removed the installed packages with the purge option but the neither GRUB or the loading screen returned to their original state. Is it possible to restore the default behaviour of these components?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1 Install grub customizer

step1.a open a terminal - hold down CTRL and ALT keys and tap T

step 1.b `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`

step 1.c `sudo apt-get update`

step 1.d `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`

step 2 run grub customizer

step 2.a select Appearance settings tab

step 2.b choose the color(s) you desire for font, background and highlighted font and background from the selections on the left of the window. Do NOT choose the same color for font and background as you will effectively blind yourself to the choices on the grub menu.

step 2.c Click save

step 3. Choose File then Install to MBR (you should get the option to choose the original drive you placed the MBR on when installing. In my case /dev/sda)

step 4. Close grub customizer

step 5. reboot.

For changing the splash screen look here.

[How to Change the Splash Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228041/how-to-change-the-splash-screen)

Comment: I will give it a try but my aim is restoring the default settings for GRUB and system splash screens.

Comment: @Vesnog I'll look into the splash screen when I get the chance.

Comment: Well thanks I am awating yoru reply my aim is to restore the pink background.

Comment: @Vesnog edited answer to provide step by step instructions. Sorry that I cannot respond exactly to the background of pink in grub as I don't recall any of the dozens of Ubuntu installations I have performed having a pink background, however the answer above should provide you with an acceptable result. Perhaps you want light red?

Comment: @Vesnog If you decide to use an image for a background you'll need to convert it to PNG to get it to work. This is easily done in GIMP

Comment: Thanks I will give these a try, I did not have time earlier.